# How to find out which model/code generated a particular SQL query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I can see many cached SQL commands (around 1 000) running in my console when loading a page.

I can´t find what row of code fires these SQL queries. Is there any tool which tells me in what a model and row SQL query is generated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet).

It detects n+1 queries and tells you where they are from.